# Python file read line startswith to endswith and move to list

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have file like below:

```
=======
line1 contents
line2 contents
line3 contents
=======
=======
line4 contents
line5 contents
=======
=======
line6 contents
line7 contents
=======
```

Read file contents that startswith ======= to endswith =======. Send output to list.

Below is expected output for list of list

```
 [["line1 contents", "line2 contents", "line3 contents"],
  ["line4 contents", "line5 contents"],
  ["line6 contents", "line7 contents"]]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where's the problem?

Comment: Please take some time to read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your input text is stored in variable `s`, you can use the following list comprehension:

```
[l.splitlines() for l in s.split('=======\n')[1::2]]
```

With your sample input, this returns:

`[['line1 contents', 'line2 contents', 'line3 contents'], ['line4 contents', 'line5 contents'], ['line6 contents', 'line7 contents']]`